# how to create/load a custom spring jar in a not spring managed web application

Tags: spring, jar, applicationcontext

I would like to create a jar lib using spring and import them in my web application. Since I use spring in the latter too, then I don't have any problem. The point is that I would like to re-use it in non spring managed environment too. 
Let's say I want to use the lib in pure javaee web app, then I can't use the spring autowiring and package scan features. 
My idea is: create a simple pure bean and load spring configuration in its costructor:

```
public class SpringStandalone{

private Client                      client;
private AnnotationConfigApplicationContext  ctx;

public SpringStandalone() {
    ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
    ctx.getEnvironment().setActiveProfiles("test");
    ctx.scan("my.package.scan");
    ctx.refresh();
    client = (Client) ctx.getBean(Client.class);
    ctx.destroy();
}

public void send(Object o) {
    client.send(o);
}

}
```

Is that the right way to do this? If so, How should I manage the applicationContext destroy (should I bother about it?)?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Fabio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **can't** destroy the Spring app context and hope that your Client object will work. 
Instead, you should provide a separate '*SpringStandalone.destroy()*' method that the client code will call when your SpringStandalone class is no longer required.

Note that the call to *ctx.destroy()* not just clears the Spring container, but also triggers some 'business' actions, such as calling all bean methods annotated with *@PreDestroy*, publishing shutdown events etc., so it is a good practice to call it when you no longer need the SpringStandalone object.

I believe there is nothing wrong in your approach. 
Note that it takes time for the Spring app context to load, so you would want to create your SpringStandalone only once.

Comment: well, in the meanwhile I changed the springStandalone class to a singleton in order to get only one instance (as you suggested). since the client must live as long as the hosting web app lives then I guess the destroy operation matches the application shut down. Am I right? In any case thanks for the answer.

Comment: Yes, if the Client bean should live as long as the app lives, the destroy operation should match the app shutdown. As to the singleton, in my opinion it's only one of possible solutions, the obvious drawback is that this is a global variable with all its deficiencies. Another note: you want to detect your Spring configuration issues on your app start up, but the singleton pattern might defer the SpringStandalone creation until its first use, so I'd suggest to make an explicit call to trigger creation on your app start up.